# Synchronize default application settings across Windows installations

Tags: windows

On Windows 7, is it possible to synchronize the default application settings between multiple computers? I'd like to set Google Chrome as the default browser on multiple computers, and synchronize the changes automatically, so that the default web browser will change on all computers if I change it on one computer.

(First, I'll need to know where the default application settings are stored on Windows, and how they can be accessed.)

Comment: It's possible to transfer the default applications list from one computer to another under Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/a/184549/71277

Comment: This sounds like a job for Group Policy!

Comment: Many of these settings are in registry and I have never heard of any tool that will synchronize registry across computers. You'll probably need to setup a domain environment and use roaming profiles if you really want to have all your settings carried around with you on multiple computers.